# SSD with profile on HDD - minor issues

Tags: windows-8

I am practising an installation of Windows 8 in a VM before I do it on my real machine. I installed it using this guide [User Profiles - Relocate to another Partition or Disk](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/4275-user-profiles-relocate-another-partition-disk.html) and it boots up OK and everything looks ok, except the apps.

When I try and load Google Chrome it fails (nothing happens). The Mail app fails to run. Solitaire works, weather app fails. Maps works, but photos fails to load.

Any ideas what I need to do?

The C:\Users folder is empty, and D:\Users has all my folders in it, so it LOOKS OK, but some apps fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way and it works a treat.
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/87555-user-profile-change-default-location.html

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Start corner > Command Prompt (Admin) > Yes > Type:

```
C:
mklink /j C:\Users U:\Users
mklink /j C:\ProgramData U:\ProgramData
```

Replace the "U:\" text with your own drive letter. Each line has a separate command that you press enter to execute.

When you open Explorer to the C drive, you should see the "Users" and "ProgramData" junctions that look like folders.

You must now create a new user account. The Metro apps should work.

Source:

- http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/4275-user-profiles-relocate-another-partition-disk-2.html?p=130111#post130111

---

patrickd314:

> PC Pilot -- Did you follow Kari's advice to omit from your script the
>   line which refers to "program data"? It appears that if you move both
>   "program data" and "users" (which worked fine with Windows 7), that
>   Metro apps won't work. So from your "relocate.xml" script, delete the
>   line (currently line 7): e:\ProgramData .
>   This has worked fine for me; "program data" lives on the C: drive,
>   "users" on D: and Metro apps work fine (though I haven't yet found any
>   that I like!)

Source:

- http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/4275-user-profiles-relocate-another-partition-disk-2.html?p=136920#post136920

Comment: Both mklink commands give this error: `Cannot create a file when that file already exists.`

Comment: @MarkAllison, if the folders are empty, rename or delete the folders first before running the commands.